# Javascript equivalent of "something in string"

Tags: javascript, string

In python if I want to check if something is in a string, I would do:

```py
if "bar" in someString:
  ...
```

What would be the javascript equivalent of that?

Comment: At the very least, you should **search** Stack Overflow first before asking.  This question has a legendary duplicate whose best answer has over 15000 upvotes that I just don't know how you managed to miss.

Comment: @Wyck I did but I may not have wordered my search correctly and it certainly did not appear in similar searches when I was about to post this question. Lets not be too harsh here and not assume

Comment: I apologise for any harshness.  In the future you may have luck asking ChatGPT any exceedingly simple questions like this.  The exact wording you used produces something strikingly similar to Mamun's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the equivalent way to check if something exists within a string is by using the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). The [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method returns `true` if the string contains the specified value, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Duplicate.  Please don't answer.